# userscript addEventListener seemingly not attaching to element

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I'm trying to attach an onclick event listener to an existing element (notably not a `button` with a `form`, it's a simple `div`) on a webpage through a userscript. However, it appears that, even though to my knowledge adding an event listener in an anonymous function shouldn't run afoul of timeout rules for the userscript existing, it doesn't attach anything (or, possibly, it *does*, but then the userscript times out and the anonymous function stops existing, causing the event listener to fall off. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about the scope of user scripts?

I've tried attaching it to the button in the following manner. This is not caused by some obscure race condition with re-binding outerHTML to itself, because even without that line the event listener is not added.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.outerHTML = button.outerHTML; // removes all existing event listeners on the element
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.alert("ping"); // or any other function body
}, false);
```

Firefox 112.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because when you do `button.outerHTML = button.outerHTML;` the button you originally referenced is no longer the button in the DOM. You are replacing that button with a new button.

You would need to select the button again.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.outerHTML = button.outerHTML; // removes all existing event 

button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.alert("ping"); 
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Comment: Didn't strike me that it would invalidate the reference, thank you! Curious why I couldn't attach the handler even when i didn't strip the existing ones, but I'll write that up to me having done something else in the interim. Thank you o/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method ...

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');

// cloneNode does not clone event listeners
const clone = button.cloneNode(true); 

// replace button with its clone
button.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, button);

// add new addEventListener(
clone.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.alert('ping'); 
});
```

*Note: Generally speaking, DOM methods are more efficient and 5-10 times faster than `innerHTML/OuterHTML`.*

Comment: I'll keep this in mind if I go back to work on this userscript more. Still wish there was a reasonable way to remove anonymous event listeners, though.